# Default string arguments

Tags: c++

```
myPreciousFunction(std::string s1 = "", std::string s2 = "")
{
}

int main()
{
    myPreciousFunction();
}
```

Can i make the arguments look more pretty?
I want there to be empty strings if no arguments were supplied.

Comment: what do you mean by "prettier" - the code above is the correct (and only) syntax for default parameters.

Comment: I wanted to like (string s1 = 0; string s2 = 0;) in the arguments.

Comment: The missing `std::` doesn't make it prettier if you're used to C++. It only makes other people wonder wether thats actually `std::string` or not.

Comment: maybe because its easier to read.

Comment: -1 "" is an empty string already.

Comment: Oh, lord! Why is so hard to find a fashion consultant here?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you may consider this:

```
myPreciousFunction(std::string s1 = std::string(), std::string s2 = std::string())
{
}
```

But it doesn't really look prettier.

Also, if you're passing strings, you might want to pass them as `const&`:

```
myPreciousFunction(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
}
```

This is a standard way to avoid coping the data around.

Comment: I'll go with std::string s1 = std::string() because it look great!

Comment: Or to put it together: `myPreciousFunction(const std::string& s1 = std::string(), const std::string& s2 = std::string())`

Comment: @John: You have an interesting measure of prettiness.

Comment: @ John I wouldn't say it looks great but I think it looks better than anything else I can come up with.

Answer (score 18):

There is actually another solution.

```
const std::string empty = std::string();

myPreciousFunction( const std::string &s1 = empty, const std::string &s2 = empty)
```

This has the advantage of avoiding construction of temporary objects.

Comment: Hmmm, that's a clever idea, wonder would an optimiser do this anyway? Probably not I guess.

Comment: @ericcurtin No, but curiously the compiler is allowed such an optimization for certain initializer lists.

Comment: You can also use boost optional or std optional (C++17), that way you don't have to call the constructor of a string.

Comment: @Potatoswatter `user(int=0,int=0,const char *s=nullptr)` this works fine but I want to remove `s` as it is not necessary while declaration  means I want to use `const char *=nullptr` but this gives error. so please tell the what's the way ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane you simply need a space between * and =. Regards, your friendly human compiler.

Comment: @Potatoswatter it's work, I got it , thanks lot.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a braced initialisation:

```
myPreciousFunction(const std::string& s1 = {}, const std::string& s2 = {})
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use overloaded functions, e.g.

```
myPreciousFunction(std::string s1, std::string s2)
{
   // primary implementation
}

myPreciousFunction(std:string s1)
{
    myPreciousFunction(s1, "");
}
myPreciousFunction()
{
    myPreciousFunction("", "");
}
```

Though I'm not sure this is any prettier, and definitely less attractive code-wise. (Default arguments are there to avoid this.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use boost optional or std optional (C++17), that way you don't have to call the constructor of a string. This will give you truly optional arguments. These solutions are a default parameter of string ""

Answer (score -5):

You can omit the namespace qualifier to make it look cleaner.

```
using namespace std;

void myPreciousFunction(string s1 = "", string s2 = "")
{
}
```

Comment: namespaces look prettier to me.

Comment: Populating the global namespace by this is fine for source files, since no other files are affected by this.  

_But_: Doing this in a header file will populate the global for each source and header file that includes it.  It will eventually cause problems.